# i have a bug with my ship, it doesn't want to appear in my game side and i dont know why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

**these are the settings of my ship**

[image: these are the settings of my my ship]

**And these are my camera settings**

[image: and these are my camera settings]

this is the code that is added to the ship, my problem as you can see is that i can't find my ship in the game which later on caused a lot of problems :(

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControll : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 5.0f;

    float xmin;
    float xmax;

    void Start(){
        float distance = transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
        Vector3 leftmost = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,0,distance));
        Vector3 rightmost = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1,0,distance));
        xmin = leftmost.x;
        xmax = rightmost.x;

    }
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){

            transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        }else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){

            transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        }
        float newX = Mathf.Clamp (transform.position.x, xmin, xmax);
        transform.position = new Vector3 (newX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird problem. Restart Unity. Delete the `PlayerControll` script and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `PlayerControll` script has some compile time errors which must be fixed before you can proceed. Make sure that the code doesn't have any errors and as @Programmer mentioned just restart Unity or recreate the script.

And then try changing the z position of your ship. Currently both your camera and ship are at `z=0` which might be the reason why you don't see your ship. Move it back/front a bit.